# Difference between ' and " in tcpdf or php

Tags: php

I m little bit confuse in ' and ".
Im trying to create pdf.

code

```
txt='<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="Product Fault/Failure"'.if(in_array("Product Fault/Failure",$myArray)) { .' checked="checked" '.} .'>Product Fault/Failure'
```

When I executing this,getting syntax error.I just dnt know why we write in "" or '' quote and why we cant write `<?php ?>`

Comment: This has nothing to do with `tcpdf`. It's simply just not how you concat variables into a string. Use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) instead: `$str = 'foo' . ($number == 2 ? 'number is two' : 'number is not two') . ' bar';`

Comment: TCPdf all attributes must be with ", otherwise it will not work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading the documentation; http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'.....'.if(in_array("Product Fault/Failure",$myArray)) { .' checked="checked" '.} .'...'
```

This is very wrong. You can't just concatenate an `if` statement like that.

```
'.....'.(in_array("Product Fault/Failure",$myArray) ? ' checked' : '').'...'
```

Comment: This is just about as unreadable as you can get.

Comment: You'll need to use the full `checked="checked"` - sorry, I'm just too used to boolean attributes not needing the value!

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is the problem. If you must have it done inline, use the ternary operator

```
$txt='<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="Product Fault/Failure"'.(in_array("Product Fault/Failure",$myArray)?' checked="checked" ' : '') .'>Product Fault/Failure';
```

Or just make the check 1st:

```
$checked='';
if(in_array("Product Fault/Failure",$myArray)) { 
    $checked = ' checked="checked" ';
}
$txt='<input type="checkbox" name="product[]" value="Product Fault/Failure"'. $checked .'>Product Fault/Failure'
```